# NiFi ListenHTTP GET request?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently using the ListenHTTP processor to accept flow files from a different NiFi instance. This works fine but for some reason GET requests do not work. Does ListenHTTP only allow POST requests ?

This is the error I receive:

```
HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
```

P. S I am aware of a more advanced HandleHTTPRequest processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ListenHTTP` only accepts `POST` and `HEAD` requests. `GET`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` are not accepted by the processor and will return a `405` HTTP Status Code. The documentation of the processor could be improved to document this.

You are correct that to handle `GET` requests, you should use the `HandleHTTPRequest` processor.

However, if your use case is transmitting flowfiles between two NiFi instances, you will get much better behavior and performance by using the [**Site to Site**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#site-to-site) capability. This can be routed over HTTP(S) or raw sockets, provides security, integrity, load balancing, and many additional features.